# ElseIf overwrites prior if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have the following code and I think the `ElseIf` checks the same cells as the initial `If` and overwrites the cells the initial `If` altered. I assume this has to do with the difference in condition (string check vs. rowheight).

Any input to addres the problem is highly appreciated.

Edit: So it does overwrite it. Any tips as how to not make it overwrite?
      equations in both if's can be true. So I wan't the ones that are true in 
      the first if excluded from the second.

```
Dim row As Long
row = 2
Const colSelected As Long = 67, belang As Long = 71, colPref1 As Long = 74, _ 
colPref2 As Long = 78, colPref3 As Long = 82

Set rngOutput = WsStam.Range("FC2") 
Set opmerking = WsStam.Range("FB2")
With WsStam 
    lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colSelected).End(xlUp).row 

    Do Until row > lastRowInput 

        If .Cells(row, belang).Value = "Nee" Then
            rngOutput.Value = 0
            opmerking.Value = "Geen Belangstelling"

        ElseIf .Cells(row, colSelected).RowHeight > 0 Then   

            Select Case .Cells(row, colSelected).Value 
                Case .Cells(row, colPref1).Value 
                    rngOutput.Value = 0
                Case .Cells(row, colPref2).Value 
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                    opmerking.Value = Voorkeur2
                Case .Cells(row, colPref3).Value 
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                    opmerking.Value = Voorkeur3
                Case Else
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                    opmerking.Value = "Functiereeks"

            End Select

            Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) 
            Set opmerking = opmerking(2)

        End If

        row = row + 1 

    Loop

End With
```

Comment: I think issue is somewhere else. It should never test `ElseIf` condition, when `If` is `True`. Go through your code with F8 and check how it flows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should these two lines be below the `End If`?

```
Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) 
Set opmerking = opmerking(2)
```

Otherwise yes, the only time you can move on is when you enter the `Else If` state. Which might give the impression that your `Else If` is overwriting your initial `If`

---

p.s. It's more common to use `rngOutput.Offset(1,0)` rather than `rngOutput(2)` - if nothing else it's a lot more clear what's actually happening.

---

Further discussion. Look at the code below. If you iterate twice and the first time the IF condition is satisfied but the second time it's not satisfied but the ElseIf condition is.

```
Do Until row > lastRowInput 
    If .Cells(row, belang).Value = "Nee" Then
        opmerking.Value = "IF"
    ElseIf .Cells(row, colSelected).RowHeight > 0 Then   
        opmerking.Value = "ELSEIF"
        Set opmerking = opmerking.Offset(1,0)
    End If
    row = row + 1 
Loop
```

The value of opermerking is set to "IF" but then the second time it loops and the ElseIf condition is satisfied it will be set to "ELSEIF". The value is **overwritten**.

This is because you are only changing the range reference of opermerking after the ElseIf command is satisfied. The result is somthing like this:

```
ELSEIF
ELSEIF
...
```

On the other hand this changes the range reference of opmerking each time you loop:

```
Do Until row > lastRowInput 
    If .Cells(row, belang).Value = "Nee" Then
        opmerking.Value = "IF"
    ElseIf .Cells(row, colSelected).RowHeight > 0 Then   
        opmerking.Value = "ELSEIF"
    End If
    Set opmerking = opmerking.Offset(1,0) '<-- this moved outside the If...End If
    row = row + 1 
Loop
```

So your output is something like this:

```
IF
ELSEIF
ELSEIF
IF
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the second answer. I got the code somewhere else and I knew what it was doing, but not what the (2) meant (still don't). It's much more clearer in the second way of writing.
Concerning the position of the variables, I don't think it matters. This is the only place they're used.

Comment: No problem. Did you try it at least? Did it not work?

Comment: No, I tried it. Get the same results. The problem is that the (some) equations in both if's can be true at the same time.

Comment: @MyName, there is no way that for any one loop vba is entering both the `If` and `Else If` conditions. If you've managed that I would suggest you pick up the phone to Microsoft ;). Check my update for a little help to understand your code

Comment: Hi Callum. Thanks for the input. Taking the range offsets out of the 'If" does help some.
What I meant to say with the "true at the same time" is that conditions in the second 'ElseIf' are applicable to when the first condition is "nee" as well. But I guess I have to look at my logic better.